# Flip a row of the table after every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

i have an html table and i want to flip vertically each row individually of the table to display a "front" and "back" data. the flip should occur every 10s.

this website is for displaying stocks from a website and i want a table showing recently updated stocks which flip(change) every 10s

```html
<div class="row ">
<div id="draggable">
<div id="dashboard" class="shadow">
<div class="widget-inner loadable" id="a">

<div class="widget-inner loadable" id="b">
```

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:-90px">
      <div id="draggable">
           <div id="dashboard" class="shadow">
                  <div class="widget-inner loadable" id="a">

                   {% for rec in stockrecent1 %}
                   <tr>
                   <td class="name">{{rec}}</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.currentprice}}</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.change}}</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.percent}}%</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.lastprice}}</td>
                   </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
                  </div>

                   <div class="widget-inner loadable" id="b">
                   {% for rec in stockrecent %}                
                   <tr>
                   <td class="name">{{rec}}</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.currentprice}}</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.change}}</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.percent}}%</td>
                   <td class="other">{{rec.lastprice}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

    </div></div></div></div>
```

```css
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


#draggable {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 1550px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#dashboard {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

#dashboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}

.loadable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#a{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-animation: mymoveback 20s infinite;  
  animation: mymoveback 20s infinite;  
}
#b {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-animation: mymove 20s infinite;
  animation: mymove 20s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymoveback {
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  40% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes mymoveback {
  40% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}
```

this code is working normally for other elements but not working for table rows. i tried putting the for loop out of the `<div class="widget-inner loadable" id="a">` but not working. Please suggest a fix or an alternative way to do this. flip is not necessary. i just wanted to change to content of the rows using animation

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: table-row table-cell, to divs in place of tr td.

```css
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.tr { display: table-row;}
.td {display: table-cell;}

#draggable {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 1550px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#dashboard {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

#dashboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}

.loadable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#a {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-animation: mymoveback 20s infinite;
  animation: mymoveback 20s infinite;
}

#b {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 20s infinite;
  animation: mymove 20s infinite;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymoveback {
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  40% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes mymoveback {
  40% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="">
    <div id="draggable"></div>
    <div id="dashboard" class="shadow">
        <div class="widget-inner loadable" id="a">

            {% for rec in stockrecent1 %}
                                    <div class="tr">
                <div class="td name">{{ rec }}</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.currentprice }}</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.change }}</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.percent }}%</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.lastprice }}</div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="widget-inner loadable" id="b">
            {% for rec in stockrecent %}
                  <div class="tr">
                <div class="td name">{{ rec }}</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.currentprice }}</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.change }}</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.percent }}%</div>
                <div class="td other">{{ rec.lastprice }}</div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is flipping entire table together instead of flipping each row individually